# find the minimun value of $\alpha$ such that $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+\alpha}>e$ for every $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the minimun $\alpha$ such that $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+\alpha}>e$ for every $x>0$

I tried a lot but nothing was helpful :/

Comment: Did you also try the obvious, namely that $f(\alpha)$ is maximum or minimum when $f'(\alpha)=0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want $$f=(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+\alpha}-e>0$$ for any value of $x>0$, it must be true for very large values of $x$. For large values of $x$, the Taylor expansion of $f$ is given by $$\frac{e a-\frac{e}{2}}{x}+\frac{\frac{e a^2}{2}-e a+\frac{11
   e}{24}}{x^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right)$$ Then $a \geq \frac {1}{2}$ fullfills the condition.

A plot of the function $f$ for $a =\frac {1}{2}$ shows that it is always positive. If $a=0.49$ is used $f$ is negative for any $x \gt 7.84$; if $a=0.48$ is used $f$ is negative for any $x \gt 3.68$;  if $a=0.47$ is used $f$ is negative for any $x \gt 2.30$.

Comment: I think the difficult part of this problem doesn't lie at 'large' values of $x$, it, instead lies at $x \approx 0$, since we have $\lim_{x \to 0} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x = 1$.